# Dropwizard config (yml) behaves strangely

Tags: java, yaml, dropwizard

I'm working with the [Dropwizard sample project](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/example.yml) from the tutorial and faced the following strange issue:

- With the following server config

  ```
  server:
    type: default
    applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080
  ```

  My resource returns the correct response.
- When I change it to:

  ```
  server:
    type: simple
  ```

  I see (from Jetty's logs) that it was correctly registered and loaded but doesn't work - if I try the same path I see 404 in browser and

  ```
  GET /wizard-resource/rs 200
  ```

  in the logs. I've tried to find the difference between `simple` and `default` in yaml configs but Google didn't shed much light on the topic.

So, here are two questions:

1. Why with simple connector do I get a 200 in logs but 404 in browser?
2. What is the use of simple connector and when it is better than default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Dropwizard Javadocs:

[Simple Server](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/8ee4deea7c160ac47f80a8bd00762b1637575cfe/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/server/SimpleServerFactory.java)

> A single-connector implementation of {@link ServerFactory}, suitable
>   for PaaS deployments (e.g., Heroku) where applications are limited to
>   a single, runtime-defined port. A startup script  can override the
>   port via {@code -Ddw.server.connector.port=$PORT}.

[Default Server](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/8ee4deea7c160ac47f80a8bd00762b1637575cfe/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/server/DefaultServerFactory.java)

> The default implementation of {@link ServerFactory}, which allows for
>   multiple sets of application and admin connectors, all running on
>   separate ports. Admin connectors use a separate thread pool to keep
>   the control and data planes separate(ish).

It's also mentioned (though not thoroughly) in the [Configuration Reference documentation](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/configuration.html#simple).

Not sure why it's logged as 200 while it's 404, it could be a bug; but the reason you're getting 404 could be because the default `applicationContextPath` config in simple server is `/application`. So if you try

```
GET /application/wizard-resource/rs
```

it should work.